# How to get a difference between two rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to find the difference between two rows on the same column group by id

```
ID Value1 Value2

a  500 200
b  300 200
a  100 300
b  300 400
....
```

Expected output

```
ID Value1 Value2

a  400 -100
b  0 -200
....
```

How to make a query for the above condition.

Comment: How many rows are for every `ID` value ? How do you compute this difference if there are 3 or more rows for every `ID` value ?

Answer (score 3):

You can use following:

```
SELECT
    ID,
    MAX(Value1) - MIN(Value1),
    MIN(Value2) - MAX(Value2)
FROM
    myTableName
GROUP BY
    ID
```

But **there is one assumption**: the second row has always greater `Value1` and lower `Value2` than first one.

Comment: what if the one of the ID contains only 1 row? the different would be 0 then. Which I think, is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
SELECT t1.ID, max(t2.VALUE1 - t1.VALUE1)
FROM TABLE1 t1
    left join TABLE1 t2 on t1.id = t2.id
group by t1.id
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO:](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/07341/4)

Comment: what if the one of the ID contains only 1 row? the different would be 0 then. Which I think, is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

This query will give a absolute difference between max value of ID and min value of same ID:

```
SELECT ID
, ABS(MAX(VALUE1) - MIN(VALUE1)) AS v1Diff
, ABS(MAX(VALUE2) - MIN(VALUE2)) AS v2Diff
FROM TABLE1
GROUP BY ID
```

[Sql Fiidle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/211ec/4)

But if you want get a real difference(negative diff) then we need to know which row is first and which row is next. Then we can count difference like `firstRowValue - nextRowValue`.

Maybe your table has some `RowID` or `DateTime` column from where we can ordering a rows from same `ID`. 
What column/columns are `Primery Key` in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Use option with CTE and ROW_NUMBER() ranking function

```
 ;WITH cte AS
 (
  SELECT ID, 
         CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 1/0) % 2
           WHEN 1 THEN Value1
           WHEN 0 THEN -1 * Value1 END AS Value1,
         CASE ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY 1/0) % 2
           WHEN 1 THEN Value2
           WHEN 0 THEN -1 * Value2 END AS Value2
  FROM dbo.test22
  )
  SELECT ID, SUM(Value1) AS Value1, SUM(Value2) AS Value2
  FROM cte
  GROUP BY ID
```

Demo on [**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d326e/1)